# WCF Encryption/Decrpytion using both Server and Client certificates

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate

I have created a service where there would be a private cert on the server where i am hosting the service and the client will have public key of it. 
And the client would have a different private key where they will encrypt the message which they send to the endpoint i create and i have the public key for it which i will use to decrypt the message. 
What i have so far in the server config file.

So this one takes care of the main private cert where the service will be hosted. I am not sure where/how to put the public key of the cert where client has/uses the private key to encrypt the message.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpEndPointBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfJNet.ServiceBehavior" name="wcfJNetService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="basicHttpEndPointBinding"
          contract="IJNetService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="xxxxxx" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wcfJNet.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="0000xx000" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very good, you have a deep understanding of the working mechanism of the SSL certificate. Please refer to the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client
The client-side and server-side automatically negotiate the public key of the certificates during communication to encrypt the message with the other's public key and decrypt the soap message using the private key. Thereby we don’t need to manually program this procedure. It is enough to install each other’s certificate in the local certificate store.
If we authenticate the client with message security mode, we need to use the `service credential` section to configure the service certificate. Just like what you have done.

```
<serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="0000xx000" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
```

On the client-side, generally, we need to specify two certificates, one is service certificate, another is client certificate.

```
//message security, we need to specify both the default certificate and the client certificate.
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9b8db0dfe615458ace0ae9e89fcb983c5d16f633");
            try
            {
                var result = client.SayHello();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

As for the trust relationship between the certificates, on the client-side,we need to install the server certificate in the `LocalCA`, and on the server-side, we need to install the client certificate in the particular location depending on the authenticating mode. By default it is ok to install it in the `LocalCA`.

```
    //this is default authentication mode. 
  sh.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode= System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.